# Cannot read property 'updatePassword' of null

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase and I'm trying to follow the docs to allow a customer to update their password when they're logged in, but I keep getting the following error:

```
updatePassword.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updatePassword' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (updatePassword.js:10)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
```

I know there is a value because I printed the value to the console. Anyone know what's going on?

**HTML:**

```
<h6>update password</h6>
<input id="updatePasswordField" class="updatePassword" contenteditable="true" />
<button id="updatePasswordBtn">Update Password</button>
```

**JS**

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#updatePasswordBtn").click(function(){
    var password = $("#updatePasswordField").val();

    user.updatePassword(password).then(function() {
      // Update successful.
      console.log('updated');
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      console.log('failed update');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `user` is null.  Probably the user is not currently logged in.

Comment: can you check if the user object is return or null ?

Comment: based on this user is a global variable, if it's null, either the user is not logged in the time when the click happens, or the user logs in but 'user' is overwritten somewhere else in the code (if any).

Comment: Yes, let me check.

Comment: @abdoutelb Yeah, it's showing I'm logged in.

Comment: It's now showing 'update failed' in console.

Answer (score 0):

Upon doing a `console.log(error.message);` I was able to figure out what was going on. What I needed to do was also reauthenticate the user once more. So I added a new input field and asked for their current password and place the snippet of code above in a `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()` function.

More info here under **re-authenticate a user**:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password